# how to bevel 3 unconnected edges?

Tags: bevel

[image]

Like this picture ↑ I tried to dissove error faces or edges,
I tried to bevel edges one by one，
but all failed.

What I want to achieve is:
[image]

This is a draft I made by Photoshop:

[image]

I want to know that if I need to made some actions before I bevel them? or what else operations can I do?

Please help me, Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Start with a plane.
2. Add a loop cut to divide the plane into the flat part and the part to be curved.
   [image]
3. Now add a few more loop cuts to the smaller part.
   [image]
4. Turn on Proportional Editing, go to the side view, move the first two vertices downward, and adjust them to make a curve as you wish to have.
   [image]
5. Add a loop cut in the middle, delete the left side of the mesh, and add a mirror modifer.
6. Now go to front view and once again with proportional editing, move the bottom vertex and then adjust the shape to your liking.
   [image]
7. Now simply extrude the side and bottom edges to the back
   .
   [image]
8. Select all with <kbd>A</kbd> > <kbd>M</kbd> > By distance. (There will be one double vertex)
9. Select the vertices in the back, scale them to 0 on the Y-axis, and move them to whatever length you wish to.
   [image]
10. Select the curvy edge loop and set its crease to one if you wish to put a subdivision later.
    [image]

Results:
[image]

Comment: awesome! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a flat cuboid with the desired dimensions of the finished object and duplicate it in place. Scale one a bit longer on X, the other a bit wider on Y (either in *Edit Mode* or if in *Object Mode*, apply the scale afterwards with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>). I have not recreated the length ratios of your reference on my example, just used some random dimensions:

   [image: two cuboids]
2. On the longer one go to *Edit Mode*, select the two bottom side edges and bevel them.

   [image: bevel bottom edges]
3. On the wider one go to *Edit Mode*, select the front top edge and bevel it.

   [image: select top edge]
4. Now back in *Object Mode* select both objects. The simplest way would be now to first go to the *Preferences* > *Add-ons* and make sure you enable the *Bool Tool* add-on.

   [image: bool tool]
5. With the add-on enabled and both objects selected (no matter which is the active one), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad ×</kbd> to apply an "Intersect" *Boolean*.

   [image: bool tool result]
6. Probably the mesh needs a little clean up now, go into *Edit Mode*, select all with <kbd>A</kbd> and then press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*. If you maybe extend the meshes before the Boolean operation to get a cleaner overlap, this might not be necessary.

   [image: limited dissolve]
7. Here you can see the result. If you do not use  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad ×</kbd> for the *Bool Tool*, but only  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad ×</kbd>, a *Boolean* modifier will be added to the active object and not applied immediately. This way you can tweak the objects afterwards if you want to change something.

   [image: result]

Comment: This one did come to my mind, but is the topology good with this one? I did not try it for that reason.

Comment: @TheKalaakaar In my example the topology was good, it depends on how different you make the two bevels. The way I did it is more or less resulting in what you did, because the front bevel and the side bevels have the same amount of segments in both our methods. Of course if it is desired to make the bevels very different from each other, then we both have to adjust our methods... like with all Boolean methods, if you have a clean and "compatible" geometry, it works quite well - if not, well then you have to tweak or clean up a lot afterwards.

Comment: tanks you! I tried your method I think it's worked well !

Answer (score 2):

The procedural method if you want to change something afterwards:

1. Like in my other answer, create two flat cuboids, one longer, the other wider. In *Edit Mode*, give the two bottom side edges of the longer one a bevel weight of 1. On the wider one, give the top front edge a bevel weight of 1.

   [image: bevel weights]
2. Give both objects a *Bevel* modifier where you set the *Limit Method* to *Weight*. Adjust the *Amount*, *Segments*, *Profile* etc. to your liking.

   [image: bevel modifier]
3. Give one of the objects (no matter which) a *Boolean* modifier, set it to *Intersect* and choose the other cuboid as the target *Object*.

   [image: boolean modifier]

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's my first time to learn 'weight', thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cteate this shape (mirrored with a *Mirror* modifier):

[image]

Bevel the bottom edge:

[image]

Select the vertex at the top and bevel it:

[image]

Add these edges with the *Knife* tool:

[image]

Extrude the whole edge loop inwards:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your kind help!